# Failure to close channel causes indefinite blocking

Tags: clojure, core.async

Here is an example from http://www.braveclojure.com/core-async/ :

```
(defn hotdog-machine-v2 [hotdog-count]
  (let [in (chan) out (chan)]
    (go (loop [hc hotdog-count]
          (if (> hc 0)
            (let [input (<! in)]
              (if (= 3 input)
                (do
                  (>! out "hotdog")
                  (recur (dec hc))  )
                (do
                  (>! out (Exception. "Not enough payment!"))
                  (recur hc))))
            (do
              (close! in)
              (close! out)))))
    [in out]))
(let [[in out] (hotdog-machine-v2 2)]
  (>!! in "pocket lint")
  (println (<!! out))
  (>!! in 3)
  (println (<!! out))
  (>!! in 3)
  (println (<!! out))
  (>!! in 3)
  (println (<!! out))
  )
```

If I leave out the channel-closing part, then this code hangs forever, why?

Answer (score 3):

If I run this in the normal case with the close it prints this:

```
user> (let [[in out] (hotdog-machine-v2 2)]
  (>!! in "pocket lint")
  (println (<!! out))
  (>!! in 3)
  (println (<!! out))
  (>!! in 3)
  (println (<!! out))
  (>!! in 3)
  (println (<!! out)))
#error {
 :cause Not enough payment!
 :via
 [{:type java.lang.Exception
   :message Not enough payment!
 ... stack trace here ...

 [java.lang.Thread run Thread.java 724]]}
hotdog
hotdog
nil     ;; <---- look here
```

That last nil is the result of the last read from out reading the value nil, which is being sent as a result of the channel closing because the machine is out of hotdogs. Without the close that last put `(>!! in 3)` blocks waiting for somthing to read from the chan which nobody is going to do. By default **writes to core.async chans don't succeed in writing until someone is ready to read** that value

If I take out the close, and take out the last write it does not print that nil, *and* does not block:

```
user> (let [[in out] (hotdog-machine-v2 2)]
  (>!! in "pocket lint")
  (println (<!! out))
  (>!! in 3)
  (println (<!! out))
  (>!! in 3)
  (println (<!! out))
  )
#error {
 :cause Not enough payment!
 :via
 [{:type java.lang.Exception
   :message Not enough payment!
   :at ... stack trace here ...}
hotdog
hotdog
```